# Smart Word Wrap?

Tags: php, word-wrap

I'm using PHP having the following string:

```
$message = 'hello, DavidPalmerUgroImmIErogandTagroChechiken ho are you?';
```

I want to split the `word` if string's ANY word is long then `15 characters`. How can I do this?

I searched and found answers of splitting WHOLE string but not just splitting a WORD if that particular word is more then 15 characters long. Please help!

Comment: how do you want to split? add spaces in between or add hypens?

Comment: Just want to use a SPACE in between he two SPLITTED words (after splitting a LONG word)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try something like this as well.

```
$newMessage = preg_replace('/(\S{15})(?=\S)/', '$1 ', $message);
```

Comment: You're regex GEEk :P That is an excellent option. Thanks Sharma

Answer (score 3):

This is a **relatively** basic solution, and there are things you can improve on (better word detection, putting 14-letters then a hyphen for interrupted words, etc), but this should give you a good starting point.

You could also do this with regex (`/[^\s]{15,}/` as your basic starting point) if you're comfortable with that - just horses for courses :-)

---

Split the string into words:

```
$words = explode(' ', $message); // could also split on other punctuation or detect words more reliably here
```

Iterate the words to see if any are >15 letters

```
foreach ($words AS $key => $word) {
    if (strlen($word) > 15) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

then when you find one, cut it up into smaller parts

```
$words[$key] = implode(' ', str_split($word, 15));
```

and lastly, join it all back up.

```
$words = implode(' ', $words);
```

---

Complete code:

```
$words = explode(' ', $message); // could also split on other punctuation or detect words more reliably here

foreach ($words AS $key => $word) {
    if (strlen($word) > 15) {
        $words[$key] = implode(' ', str_split($word, 15));
    }
}

$words = implode(' ', $words);
```

Comment: would this work if string has three consecutive spaces?
`hello   worldasdfasdfasdfasdf   werwerwerwer`

Comment: Yes, the array entry would be an empty string (`''`), would fail `>15` so would just get put back into the output as 3 spaces

Comment: In addition, strings should never have multiple consecutive spaces, if it is normal text.

Comment: @MCEmperor "Should" isn't a programming word :P

Comment: Thanks Joe for your efforts, actually Ram Sharma's code is very short and works as expected so I have selected his answer as best one. Kind regards

Comment: @user2854563 if you also removed the upvote, would you mind putting it back? :-) Generally, upvotes are for helpful answers, accepting is for the most helpful answer. I'd like to think this was a helpful answer :-)

Comment: Yes, why not! :) You're very helpful person.

Comment: Cheers, and I'm glad you've got the problem of too many good answers :P

Answer (score 0):

Just get the size of your word with

```
$length = strlen($yourword);
```

then if thats bigger than 15, you can use [chunksplit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chunk-split.php) to separate it in smaller chunks.

Comment: The issue is, how can I find the WORD if its bigger then 15 characters?